# corona sdk pick 4 random colors from an array of colors

Tags: lua, coronasdk

How can I select 4 random colours from an array of like 12 colours and then store the 4 colours that were chosen so that the game can tell the user to find 1 of the 4 as part of a memory game.

For example if there is R,G,B,Y,P,O colours in the array list

the game then chose R,Y,B,O and displays them

The colour the player needs to find can't be Green for example, it can only be the 4 colours that were chosen at random.

I am really stuck figuring this out and any help would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one of many possible ways:

```
allColors = {"black", "white", "red", "orange", "yellow", "green",
    "blue", "indigo", "violet", "gold", "silver", "bronze"}
chosenColors = {}

while #chosenColors < 4 do
    n = math.random(1, #allColors)
    table.insert(chosenColors, allColors[n])
    table.remove(allColors, n)
end
```

Then:

```
for k, v in pairs(chosenColors) do
    print(k, v)
end
```

This will print, for example:

```
1 white
2 indigo
3 red
4 gold
```

Comment: Yes this works fine but how would you make sure it doesn't pick a duplicate? So if black is in the chosenColors table then it can't add it again

Comment: A particular color couldn't be in the `chosenColors` table more than once. Once it is chosen the first time, the `table.remove` call removes that color from the `allColors` table.

Comment: For my game its supposed to be that choosenColors table resets to nil each go and picks new colours from AllColors table again.